# image data response from jquery .ajax into new ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I'm trying to chain together the [ImageOptim API](https://im2.io/api/post) with the [OCR.space API](https://ocr.space/OCRAPI).
Both great API's by the way, I highly recommend them! The issue at hand though is that the OCR api does not accept images over 1 mb or 2600x2600 px in the free tier and thus many sources will need to be optimised before being sent.

Im running this jQuery ajax call to ImageOptim from a cordova wrapped html file:

```
var compress = function(image) {
console.log("starting compress");
$.ajax({
    url: "https://im2.io/eX4mp1E4pI/2600x2600,quality=low",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        file: image
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    crossDomain: true
}).done(function(res) {
    window.compressedImg = res;
    formData.append("file", res);
    runOCR();
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
};
```

Please note:

1. this (in my experience), will fail in the browser due to cross domain calls being blocked in the browser but not from cordova.
2. OCR compatible compression not added in yet (but would require a file size as well as dimension argument)

The output from this call is a raw png as a string, i.e. what you get when you open a .png file in a text editor. I've tried loads of ways to handle this but cannot understand how to use this data in the next ajax call (below), does it need to be saved to disk and then uploaded, if so - how? (because I tried writing it to localstorage but it would still be treated as a string).

The OCR.space call;

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("language", "MYLANGUAGE");
formData.append("apikey", "MYAPIKEY");
formData.append("isOverlayRequired", false);
function runOCR2() {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'form/multipart',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(ocrParsedResult) {
        console.log(ocrParsedResult);
    }
});
}
```

Please note; Vars are not set here but I keep them together in this question for clarity.

The response from this call is:

```
responseText: "{\"ParsedResults\":null,\"OCRExitCode\":99,\"IsErroredOnProcessing\":true,\"ErrorMessage\":\"No file uploaded or UR…"
```

i.e. the call works but the image parameter is not a valid image.

Any ideas on how to trea the returned string so that it is readable as an image for the next api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you are uploading files using formData you just pass file reference like 
`form.append('myfile',$("#fileInput").files[0])` and browser handles the encoding stuff behind the screens .It manually converts file to byte-stream and prepares appropriate boundary to help server distinguish where image begins and ends

but here scenario is different you don't have the file bound to any physical file control instead its created dynamically and you get a bytestream of that .To account for the above fact you need to tell browser **explicitly** that it's a independent raw binary stuff and should be treated as such

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data. Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native format.

```
var blob = new Blob([res], {type : 'image/png'}); //res is the converted image ImageOptim API

var formData = new FormData();
var fileName = 'myimage.png';    //filename that server will see it as
formData.append('anything', blob, fileName);
formData.append("language", "MYLANGUAGE");
formData.append("apikey", "MYAPIKEY");
formData.append("isOverlayRequired", false);

function runOCR2() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: function(response){alert(response);}
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This is very close... I had found https://github.com/acigna/jquery-ajax-native that adds response type support to support blobs but your solution seems to make that obsolete; Where your solution fails is the specification of the uploaded file. With your initial solution no argument is passed for the option "file", changing "anything" to "file" results in an error, removing the filename parameter gives an error because the image does not have a valid extension

Comment: Adding

var fileOfBlob = new File([blob], fileName);

formData.append('file', fileOfBlob);

makes the blob a file that should be possible to send "as is" - in the console it looks Ok but I still get an error from the API that filesize must be greater than 0

Comment: In traditional forms with `<file name='myfile`>` controls what you pass as the `name` is exactly what is "anything" its just an envelope marker for posted data but what server would see as a filename for the file is given by `fileName` .I don't know if you use php or not but the  `$_FILES` aray on server would be like this `Array
(
    [anything] => Array
    (
        [name] => myimage.png
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJvSJ94
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 950
    )

)` i don't know though why the error

Comment: yes File is a child of Blob with "more" stuff it may be possible

Comment: Try changing order , appending auth data first and image later tweaking some ajax option

Comment: Unfortunately changing the order doesn't do anything, here the api specifically asks for the file to be sent under the parameter "file"

Comment: Checked the code with option "file" and without filename it's working locally  what error do u get from server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126346/discussion-between-hessius-and-novice).

Comment: Too many revisions to really nail down what made this call work; A big factor was using a jQuery plugin called jQuery-formdata https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-formdata which adds support for DataType; Sending a blob with an appended filename as the file parameter was probably crucial. Thanks!